# Row operations, matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question concerning matrices that I'm not to sure about how to begin. Mostly I don't understand what the question is asking for.

Could someone please explain to me what the question is asking for? and how I should go about answering it.

[image: Question]

Thankyou for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Why did I get a -1 for?

Comment: Not sure, but don't forget to accept an answer that you are satisfied with!!

Comment: Done! Thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice, taking (Row 2) minus (Row 1) gives us
$$[0 \hspace{.5em} 2 \hspace{.5em} -2]$$
which is what we want for the second row of B.
To capture this idea as a matrix we'll use
$$C_1 = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right)$$
If we multiply $C_1 A$ we'll get a new matrix $A_1$ whose first and third rows are unchanged from $A$, but the second row matches the second row of $B$.
From here you can proceed to find a matrix $C_2$ that will change the first row of $A_1$ to match the first row of $B$.
Altogether, you should get a product
$$C_3 C_2 C_1 A = B$$
 Defining $C = C_3 C_2 C_1$,  we can conclude that $C A = B$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to start with the augmented matrix $[I|A]$ and perform row operations on this until the "$A$ side" becomes the matrix $B$, and then the "$I$ side" will automatically become the $C$ you seek. You will have $[C|B]$ in the end.